# 'bool' object not iterable

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0, face-api

I am working on python3, opencv 3.4 and using Microsoft Azure's FaceAPI function 'CF.face.detect()'
As far as I know, 'for loop' needs iterable object to run on like list but simple boolean is not iterable. Though 'res1' is a list I get this error.

TypeError: 'bool' object not iterable

Please help, Thanks in advance

Here is the code:
    import unittest
    import cognitive_face as CF
    from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
    import time
    import cv2
    from time import strftime

```
CF.Key.set('') 
#print(CF.Key.get()) 
CF.BaseUrl.set('https://southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/')
#print(CF.BaseUrl.get())
"""Setup Person and Person Group related data."""
person_group_id = '' #id from training terminal
"""Unittest for `face.detect`."""

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('1.mp4') 
while(cap.isOpened()): 
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    print("\n\n ##########.... LOOKING FOR FACES ....##########  \n\n")
    res1 = []
    print(type(res1))
    res1 = CF.face.detect(cap)

    print('\n This is the res1:  ', res1) 
    c = len(res1)
    print('\nTOTAL FACES FOUND:', c) 

    detect_id = [] ##error was here so put exception
    for i in range(c):
        print("\n\n ##########.... DETECTING FACES ....##########  \n\n")
        print('\n This is i in range c', i, c)
        detect_id.append(res1[i]['faceId'])
        #print('\n\n detected faces id ', detect_id[i])

        width  = res1[i]['faceRectangle']['width'] 
        height = res1[i]['faceRectangle']['height']
        x      = res1[i]['faceRectangle']['left']
        y      = res1[i]['faceRectangle']['top']
################## IF ENDS #########################################################################
cv2.imshow('image',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
            break
################ WHILE ENDS ####################################
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jonasz is right, you should be detecting faces on images, meaning, in frames from your mp4 file.

The method `CF.face.detect` expects an URI, so in the following code we'll write it to disk before pass it onto `CF.face.detect`:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('1.mp4') 
count = 0  # <--
while(cap.isOpened()): 
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    filename = "frame%d.jpg" % count  # <--
    cv2.imwrite(filename, img)  # <--
    count+=1  # <--

    print("\n\n ##########.... LOOKING FOR FACES ....##########  \n\n")
    res1 = []
    print(type(res1))
    res1 = CF.face.detect(filename)  # <--
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you use `CF.face.detect` on your captured image not on `cap` variable?

Comment: I am trying to detect faces on video '1.mp4'. Can not write it directly in CF.face.detect

Comment: But as far as I understand 'CF.face.detect' function accepts image as argument and you're trying to pass video there. I'm not familiar with this library, but I think the concept is to capture separate frames from video. Then detect faces on them passing captured images to the function.